# summation to integral, multiplication to what?

Tags: measure-theory

I have 2 sequences, a(n) & b(n), that share a property. The product a(n)/b(n) for all n is 1. I want keep that property but extend it to the real numbers. Essentially, keep the product a(x)/b(x) for all x in (0,1) equal to 1. I don't know if the infinite product symbol is appropriate since it suggests that the product is based off a sequence and there isn't a sequence for the real numbers for (0,1).

To make an analogy, it's similar to summation to an integral. Multiplication to a __?

Comment: If they're positive that's equivalent to $\log(a(n)) - \log(b(n)) = 0$. I don't know anything about this, but perhaps multiplicative calculus is relevant.

Comment: You might want to look at the Wikipedia page on the [Product Integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_integral) and see if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: I don't get this. If $a(n)/b(n)=1$, then $a(n)=b(n)$, so your two sequences are identical. So what are you trying to do? How does this relate to an integral. Are you talking about the concept referenced by @YiFan ?

Comment: Never mind,  I figured it out. Thank you for your help.